# Which element does myVar bind to? Problems with `ng-init`

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-ng-init

I'm wondering what's happening behind the scenes when using `ng-init`.

Sometimes `ng-init` does some unexpected things, and I have a hard time debugging.

---

Let's say I have the following structure:

```
<!-- App -->
<div ui-view>

    <!-- Component -->
    <custom-component>

        <!-- Transcluded component -->
        <transcluded-component>

            <!-- Controller -->
            <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

                <!-- Element -->
                <div ng-init="myVar = 'hello'">

                    {{myVar}}

                </div>
            </div>
        </transcluded-component>
    </custom-component>
</div>
```

Which element does `myVar` bind to?

---

**Edit 2017-07-21: Added an example**

In the following template block (especially within an `ng-repeat`), I may use an `ng-init`:

```
<span ng-init="path = getPath()">
    <a ng-if="path" ng-href="path">
        Click here
    </a>
    <span ng-if="!path">
        Some text
    </span>
</span>
```

In this case, I skipped a function call twice, and kept my template clean.

Comment: The question is not "that it does some unexpected things", I was stating that "I'm wondering what's happening behind the scenes when using ng-init", and my question was "Which element does myVar bind to?".

Comment: The [ng-init directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)  evaluates an Angular Expression in the context of the scope of its element. Numerous directives (`ng-repeat`, `ng-controller`, `ng-if`, `ng-view`, etc.) create their own scope. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Reference - scopes](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope). See also [AngularJS Wiki - Nuances of Scope Prototypical Inheritance](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for! If you can update your answer with this, I will gladly mark it as accepted.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sometimes `ng-init` does some unexpected things, and I have a hard time debugging.*

The [ng-init directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) evaluates an Angular Expression in the context of the scope of its element. Numerous directives (`ng-repeat`, `ng-controller`, `ng-if`, `ng-view`, etc.) create their own scope.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Reference - scopes](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)
- [AngularJS Wiki - Nuances of Scope Prototypical Inheritance](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

---

## Avoid using `ng-init`

Avoid using `ng-init`. It tangles the Model and View, making code difficult to understand, debug and maintain. Instead initialize the Model in the controller.

From the Docs:

> ## ngInit
>
> > This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of `ngInit`, such as for aliasing special properties of `ngRepeat`, as seen in the demo below; and for injecting data via server side scripting. Besides these few cases, you should use [controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) rather than `ngInit` to initialize values on a scope.
>
> [— AngularJS ng-init Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

---

#### Update

> Q: I've also added an example of a code block I sometime use.
>
> ```
>         <!-- Controller -->
>         <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
>             <!-- Element -->
>             <div ng-init="myVar = 'hello'">
>                 {{myVar}}
>             </div>
>         </div>
> ```

To do the equivalent initialization in the controller:

```
app.controller("MyVar", function($scope) {
    this.$onInit = function() {
        $scope.myVar = 'hello';
    };
});
```

By [separating concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) of Model and View, the code becomes easier to understand, debug and maintain.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, however, this does not answer my question about the bindings. I've also added an example of a code block I sometime use.